# Get data from 'Google Calendars' - Interesting Calendars

Tags: google-calendar-api

Google has these awesome public calendars which you can subscribe to.
An example of it would be 'Festival'. So if there is some festival, your Google Calendar will automatically add it to your appointment.

Here is their help page http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37098

My question is, how can I get the date for any event?

I haven't found any url or rss feed to take that data. is there any JSON feed?

Answer (score 0):

If you go the Calendar Setting of the interesting calendar, you can find the Calendar Address under Calendar Details.

There you should find the address in all formats (XML, ICAL and HTML) along with the Calendar ID.

Comment: unfortunately the calendar which I didn't have any xml address due to licensing issues... so I went ahead and rolled my own script to create a JSON feed.